# how to generate the report query without using the dimesion attribute for google DFP ad exchange API

Tags: python, google-dfp

I am trying generate the report by using only Dimension and columns (excluding Dimension Attribute ) For the DFP_API ad_exchange there is no Dimension Attribute for my requirement . Please help me out in generating the report .Please find the below report query

```
report_job = {
      'report_Query': {
          'dimensions': ['AD_EXCHANGE_AGENCY'],

          'statement': filter_statement,
          'columns': ['AD_EXCHANGE_INVENTORY_SIZE', 'AD_EXCHANGE_URL_ID'],
          'dateRangeType': 'CUSTOM_DATE',
          'startDate': start_date,
          'endDate': end_date
      }
  }
```